# How to dynamically call Cast<T>

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, casting

I have a `List<object>` that I want to cast to a strongly typed array. The problem is that I don't know the list type at compile time, as it can be one of many objects.

Essentially if I have `Type objectType = list[0].GetType()` I want to be able to call `list.Cast<objectType>().ToArray()`.

How can I do this? I tried using Reflection as follows:

```
Type listType = list[0].GetType();
MethodInfo castMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Cast", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
castMethod = castMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { listType });
castMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { list});
```

The invocation returns a CastIterator which appears to have no public methods.

Comment: How do you plan to **use** the results?

Comment: @ReedCopsey The underlying reason for this is when the system stashes things into an object cache. The reason that I don't know the type ahead of time is that it is a common caching method which shallow clones a domain object to remove any references it's holding to avoid reference leaks (i.e. database connections, files, etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use:

```
MethodInfo castMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Cast", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
castMethod = castMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { listType });
object castIterator = castMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { list});
var toArrayMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("ToArray", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
toArrayMethod = toArrayMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { listType });
object theArray = toArrayMethod.Invoke(null, new[] {castIterator});
```

At the end of this, `theArray` will be an array that's strongly typed.

Comment: Thanks! Works a treat.